# Ubuntu KVM guests randomly boot into emergency mode

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I'm setting up a Ubuntu 16.04 virtualization server. I have 10 Ubuntu 16.04 guest VMs that are thin provisioned based on the same master. My guests randomly boot into emergency mode.

It looks like it is caused by a remote file system that I'm trying to mount during boot. Could that really the boot process to stop?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Had something to do with the virtio folder i was trying to mount. I guess a timing issue of some sort. I worked around it by commenting out teh follwing line I added to my fstab:

## /config /mnt/config 9p trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L 0 0

I'm using a mount command in rc.local instead. Not pretty but it seems to work.